# Joining a MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to join a table in PHP so I can show the degree name from the degree table.

below is the code, which, works when I query in MySQL.  However, when the information is pulled into the html table it shows the first and last name but there's a blank where the major name would be.

**student table**

student info...

degree (int)

**degree table**

pkID (int)

degreeName (varchar2)

```
$pkID = $_GET['id'];
echo "Student ID: " . $pkID;

//create the connection
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_password = '********';
$mysql_db = 'database';

//create conection
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT s.fname,s.lname, d.degreeName FROM students s,      degree d WHERE s.degree = d.pkID AND s.id = " . $pkID);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>F Name</th>
<th>L Name</th>
<th>Major</th>
</tr>";

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['degreeName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Do you use `mysqli_fetch_*` at some point? Can you add the HTML code that you use to show the data?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. If that is so, please ask your teacher why you are learning this old-school, poorly readable and inflexible way of joining.

Comment: Also - use parametrized statements to do this:

http://www.terjemar.net/php/2011/09/using-mysqli-and-parameterized-statements/

Comment: This is for a capstone project and I have never used PHP before.  The join is just how I was taught in my previous course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your JOINs *explicit*:

```sql
SELECT s.fname, s.lname, d.degreeName
FROM students s INNER JOIN degree d
  ON s.degree = d.id
WHERE s.id = $pkID
```

MySQL *can* do some internal fudgery to get what it *thinks* you want, but it won't always work the way you expect, or at all sometimes.

In your original query SQL is going to try to do a full `CROSS JOIN`, aka attach every row in `students` to every row in `degree`, and then filter based on your `WHERE` conditions. You might not notice this being bad when you have 10 rows in each table, making that `CROSS JOIN` temp table a measly 100 rows. But if each had 1000 rows, and the `CROSS JOIN` temp table would involve *1,000,000* rows.

Also, you should *really* look into parameterizing your queries, or at least sanitizing your inputs. Concatenating variables like `$pkID` into your query is how SQL injection happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT s.fname,s.lname, d.degreeName FROM students s  inner join degree d on s.degree = d.pkID WHERE s.id = " . $pkID);
```

Comment: This provides no result in the table.